# Number of opened files is not taking effect in session

Tags: bash

In linux script, number of opened files are not taking effect in same session. `limits.conf` file has been modified successfully. Although if i open new session, it shows new value of number of opened files
(command - ulimit -Sn).

Code written in test.sh is as follows :-

```
>loading.log
ulimit -Sn >> loading.log
sudo sed -i 's/soft nofile 2048/soft nofile 1024/g' /etc/security/limits.conf
ulimit -Sn >> loading.log
```

Comment: What new session? `ulimit -Sn` without any other argument just reports the current setting. All you are doing is editing some file that the shell does not read between queries. There's no new shell, and no attempt to change the limit in that shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes in `limits.conf` take only effect after logging in again. See [do changes in /etc/security/limits.conf require a reboot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108603/do-changes-in-etc-security-limits-conf-require-a-reboot).

Perhaps it is sufficient to manually set the limit for the current shell session too.

```
# for next login
sudo sed -i 's/soft nofile 2048/soft nofile 1024/g' /etc/security/limits.conf
# for this shell session
ulimit -Sn 1024
```